# Insert Data into Foreign Key Table VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How can I Insert Data into Foreign Key Table?

I have two tables in database `Addemployees` and `Normal_L` contain one relationship which is the ID.I want to insert data into `Normal_L` Table where the ID must stay related with `Addemployees` Table.

```
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim RA As Integer
    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT into Normal_L (fromD,toD,DScrip) VALUES ('" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "') where ID ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", cn)
            cmd.Connection = cn
            RA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Process successful!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            cn.Close()
        End If
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()

End Sub
```

I hope that you can help me with that

Comment: INSERT ... WHERE doesnt exist. With a foreign key you shouldnt be able to insert into Normal_L if the key doesnt exist in Addemployees. Note that an error will be raised if the constraint of your foreign key on Normal_L.ID is not matched

Comment: would you mind telling me how to get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so if you want to do it properly use a stored procedure as such :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcName]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @fromD nvarchar(50), --yourType
     @toD nvarchar(50), --Type
     @DScrip nvarchar(50), --yourType
     @ID int
 AS
 BEGIN
     -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
     -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT into Normal_L (fromD,toD,DScrip) 
    SELECT  @fromD ,
            @toD,
            @DScrip
    FROM Addemployees 
    WHERE Addemployees.ID = @ID
END
```

This stored procedure will prevent not only the sql injections from your previous code but if you read closelly the select will only select something if the id in Addemployee is matched with your parameter. Again you could use a simple foreign key but since i dont know the structure of your base i cant tell.

now for your VB code :

```
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim RA As Integer
    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand("YourProcName", cn)
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromD", DateTimePicker2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toD",DateTimePicker1.Text )
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DScrip",TextBox5.Text )
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ComboBox1.Text)
            RA = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Process successful!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            cn.Close()
        End If
     Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Error!", "exit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()

 End Sub
```

you need to change the types in the stored procedure i dont know what you are using. Your final code should look roughly like that.

hope this helps